# Using curl to download lots of image files but can only download maxium of 21 files

Tags: php, image, curl, download

Hey I am using curl to download image files, but It can only download a maxium of 21 images after that I get the maxium execution time error.

```
$rh = fopen($imagelink, 'rb');
        $wh = fopen($imagepath, 'w+b');
        if (!$rh || !$wh) {
            echo 'error';;
        }
        while (!feof($rh)) {
            if (fwrite($wh, fread($rh, 4096)) === FALSE) {
            return false;
        }
        echo ' ';
        flush();
        }
        fclose($rh);
        fclose($wh);
```

i got this code from stackoverflow.

Hey it was my fault i was use a random and md5 function, and it did not generate more thant 21 random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

use set_time_limit ( 0 ); so that it won't timeout

Comment: I have tried this, but its not downloading more than 21 files into that folder, like if i delete 3 files then it will download 3 more files but it wont have more than 21 files.